# Error: No such file (sftp liximomo extension)

Tags: ftp, sftp, visual-studio-code

I have this problem when I upload a file on the server using the extension [`liximomo/vscode-sftp`](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp) for visual studio code.

```
[error] Error: No such file
    at SFTPStream._transform
    at SFTPStream.Transform._read
    at SFTPStream._read
```

How I can fix this problem? I tried to upload files to different servers, so I guess it's not a server-related problem but an extension.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is apparently a brand new problem that has been introduced into the newer versions of VS Code.  I have ***FOUND* A SOLUTION** that seems to work well, by modifying a single line in the extension code.  *This is only valid for version 1.12.9 of the liximomo.sftp extension.*

Here are the steps:

1. Shutdown / Quit VS Code.
2. Locate the following file:
   **Mac OS X:**

   `~/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/sftp.js`
   **Windows:**
   `C:\Users\account_name\.vscode\extensions\liximomo.sftp-1.12.9\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\sftp.js`
3. Make a backup copy of the file.
4. Modify line 388, which should be:
   `if ( code === STATUS_CODE . OK ) {` **changing it to:**
   `if (code === STATUS_CODE.OK || code === STATUS_CODE.NO_SUCH_FILE) {`
5. Save the file.
6. Relaunch VS Code; test by uploading or downloading from your sftp server.  The error should not be present.

---

The alternative solution involves downgrading your version of VS Code. *This is not desirable as you are not getting the latest fixes, security patches, etc..*

See the following links regarding this issue:

- https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/266
- https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/569 (repeat)
- https://gitmemory.com/issue/liximomo/vscode-sftp/915/827578565 (note, this site has a bad SSL certificate).

If you want to downgrade your VS Code; use this link to find the older versions:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55

---

**CREDIT**:
Bao from: https://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=pcgun70&logNo=222341271496
From their blog entry (translated by Google to English):

> "At first, there was no solution, but Now, 12 hours later, the Holy
> One appeared, who told me how to solve it.files that sftp cannot find
> in the first place.  There is a calling phrase, VScode is upgraded and
> an error is called. It came out. Actually, I did not solve the
> problem.  Even if the file is not found, the same result as the
> success process is exported.  It is just a modification. It is
> expected that a modified version will be released in the future."

Comment: That worked for the time being but wonder why the add-in was released with this bug... shouldn't they have tests in place or some sort of quality check? This was a tiny one but imagine it would have affected upload and F*** things up on the server! Scary that it's used by 800k devs. Thanks for the quick fix man!

Comment: Actually this add-on has worked fantastic for many months; it was a recent change to the VS Code base that caused the add-on to start misbehave.   The only issue is the maintenance of the add-on by the developer .. whom we have not yet heard from.  So the community has kicked in and found a solution.

Comment: This worked for me -> kubuntu linux, its not the first time I'd have to donwgrade vs code, but this time I coould solve it, thank you

Comment: It didn't help me. SFTP v1.12.9. VSC 1.59.0

Comment: Tried it's working to me.
macos big sur 11.4
liximomo.sftp-1.12.9 
vscode 1.59.1 (Universal)

Comment: Yippee -- worked for me under widows 10 -- I'm in a better mood already today!

Answer (score 93):

There is a better fix on GitHub that works for upload and download via SFTP extension:

> Do a search inside `~/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/sftp.js` for `options.emitClose = false;`
>
> Add `options.autoDestroy = false;` after both instances.
>
> - [mrjcgoodwin](https://github.com/mrjcgoodwin) commented [8 days ago](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/919#issuecomment-838586635)

Comment: This link shows where to make the changes
https://github.com/Natizyskunk/ssh2-streams/commit/e1db386ff9b0fc145c67dc13ada3e969d59cc51f#diff-11c2413775403ed66594f387ae0a38ec06ed746902424f86c7cbbbc7e395f4ca

Comment: did microsoft micromanaged a "solution" to this bug?
@ryan.s the link is not working :( but thanks anyways..

Comment: Tried but not working. 
macos big sur 11.4
liximomo.sftp-1.12.9 
vscode 1.59.1 (Universal)

Comment: I'm curious, how did you manage to get this solution? I mean, how did you debug the issue? I just want to know if you don't mind

Comment: Deliciously hacky. Solved it for me, thanks for the answer.

Comment: This works for me too. I just need to close and then open the VS Code again after modifying sftp.js. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, it works. Thanks. Remember to restart VSCode. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Wonderful! Worked for me too

Comment: Thanks! On Windows do not forget to restart your VSCode after applying fix.

Comment: Really the best solutions....

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the problem, but solution in another (simple) way:

1. install Run On Save VSCode extension
2. write a deploy.sh script along the lines

   ```
   rsync -avz -e 'ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' --exclude '.history' --exclude '.vscode' --exclude '.git' --exclude '.gitignore' --exclude 'deploy.sh' ./ user@domain.net:/home/user/public_html/
   ```
3. add the following configuration to VSCode settings.json to trigger the deploy.sh script on file save:

   ```
   "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".*",
                "isAsync": false,
                "cmd": "${workspaceFolder}/deploy.sh"
            },            
        ]
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to the second one:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is another solution only upgrading the `ssh2` package from the extension.
You just need to go to the extension path:

**Windows:**
`C:\Users\your-user\.vscode\extensions\liximomo.sftp-1.12.9`

When you are there, change the version of `ssh2` package on the `package.json` file to `^1.1.0`. Finally, just run `npm install`.

You should restart VSCode.

Alternatively, you could use a fork of the repository that is active and fixing these issues: https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp